# How do I keep my bed sheets organized?

Tags: home, storage, organization, bedroom

I have several sets of bed sheets, and I would like to keep the like patterns together, ideally in a way that does not make my linen closet a total mess. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this may come across a somewhat trivial response... But have you tried folding them up before putting them away?

I like to make sort of towers with my sheets in order to keep them all together - so have the duvet cover on the bottom as it is the biggest, then the bed sheet, followed by the pillow cases.

An issue might be that the bed sheet is the hardest to fold if it is a fitted one so below is an image of how you can fold it up neatly to go in with your piles.

[image]

If you keep them all folded and organised in the cupboard then you shouldn't have a problem with them causing a mess. You could always find a couple of old boxes to pop them in or a carrier bag or something similar to avoid them inadvertently falling apart from each other.

Comment: So, using the flat sheet as a storage container for the other parts? That's also pretty nice! Probably a bit nicer than using the pillowcase, even. I'll have to try that approach and maybe even switch to it.

Answer (score 4):

I use one of each sheet sets' pillow cases as a container for the other parts of each set.  Fold the flat and fitted sheet in the normal way, and place them into the pillow case. If there is a second pillow case, fold it up and put it into the storage case as well.  In that way, your sheet set stays organized and fits onto whatever storage shelf you use in a neat little bundle.

Comment: This is a good answer, but please add a little bit more information to the answer as it is a little short doesn't contain any information regarding how you put them in the pillow cases etc...

Comment: @MrPhooky It seemed kind of obvious... It's the storage in the pillow case that amazes people when they see it, not the specific way in which I folded things. :) But I added a little more detail.